# PHP code works on server but throws errors in localhost

Tags: php

```
for($i=0;$cast_row = mysql_fetch_array($res);$i++)
{
    $cast['id'][] = $cast_row['user_id'];
    $cast['role'][] = $cast_row['role'];
    $cast['role_name'][] = $cast_row['role_name'];
    $cast['is_approved'][] = $cast_row['is_approved'];
    $cast['movie_id'][] = $cast_row['movie_id'];
}
for($i=0;$i<count($cast['id']);$i++) //LINE 31
{
    $output .= "<tr>";
    $mname = getMovieNameById($m_id);
    $output .= "<td><a href='single.php?id=$m_id'>$mname</a></td>";

    $aname = getArtistNameById($cast['id'][$i]);
    $output .= "<td><a href=project.php?id={$cast['id'][$i]}>$aname</a></td>";
}
```

This code works fine in the web server but throws errors(notice) when executed on localhost

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\Tinyflick\managemovie.php on line 31

What can be the problem? The rest of the code seems to work just fine

Comment: It might be that your error reporting level is different on localhost compared to web server.

Comment: That might be it, but have you checked that your local database has all the columns in place?

Comment: are you sure that you've set up mysql correctly on localhost?

Comment: Can there be a problem in future if i ignore this notice?
I did not initialize each and every index of the $cast array, is that okay?

Comment: @madfriend Yeah very sure my server and local host have the exactly same database

Comment: @Abhijith Venkata: add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginning and see if the server will give you the same warning.

Comment: @nico Yeah SAME NOTICES on same lines
So what does it mean?

Comment: @Joe5150 My local database is an exact replica of the ever database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of a silly mistake..
Its solved. Thanks to nico's comment

The error reporting level in localhost is different from the one on the server.
Changing that will do the trick.
The following code will show the all the errors and warnings

```
error_reporting(E_ALL)
```

Warnings are usually disabled on a production server. For more info refer the [documentation of the said function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 0):

i guess the mysql result is just empty ! :)
try dumping the content of the row you get back.

btw, you could improove your code by doing something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) { // iterates as long there is content
    //do something with the $row... like your second for block! ;)
}
```

Comment: No, the result is getting retrieved and echoed but I'm getting warnings

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that `$cast array` is empty as you are not properly fetching the data from database.

if the error reporting is turned off in your server then you will not see any errors.

instead of for loop use the while loop, to iterate through the data fetched from database.

```
$cast = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $cast['id'][] = $row['user_id'];
    $cast['role'][] = $row['role'];
    $cast['role_name'][] = $row['role_name'];
    $cast['is_approved'][] = $row['is_approved'];
    $cast['movie_id'][] = $row['movie_id'];
}
```

and then you can run the for loop.

Comment: Data is being fetched from the database and echoed properly. The warnings are bothering me

Comment: array
  'id' => 
    array
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'role' => 
    array
      0 => string 'Action' (length=6)
  'role_name' => 
    array
      0 => string 'MAN' (length=3)
  'is_approved' => 
    array
      0 => string '0' (length=1)
  'movie_id' => 
    array
      0 => string '252YZ5gY34' (length=10)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you want supress those notices, add the following line before the loop:

```php
$cast = array('id'=>array(), 'role'=>array(), 'role_name'=>array(), 'is_approved'=>array(), 'movie_id'=>array() );
```

to initialize the variable.